# How to create a package for a React Component that supports material ui versions 4 and 5?

Tags: reactjs, npm, material-ui

I have a custom react component published on npm. It has a peer dependency for material-ui v4 `"@material-ui/core": "^4.9.1"`.

Is it possible to also support material ui v5 `"@mui/material" : "5.2.2"`? So that my component is compatible with both versions of material-ui

Comment: I never had a chance like this, but I guess you could keep both modules and import components from them separately like from `@mui/material` in case of MUI v5 or `@/material-ui/core` in case of v4.

Comment: It might be desirable to publish 2 versions of your own.

Comment: can you share the package you've created?
thanks

Comment: https://github.com/tran-simon/material-duration-picker